# Not able to access parameter passed in RESTful web service

Tags: rest, jax-rs

I have created a RESTful web service. It is working fine when I run it. But whenever I pass any parameter to that web service through the URL created, I am not able to access that parameter.
The URL of web service is:
http://localhost:8080/Web_service/path/simple/sam
where sam is the parameter passed by me and path is used for accessing the class.
In my web service, I am trying to access the passed parameter as shown in the screenshot below:
This is my code's screenshot

[image: screenshot]

I do not get back the parameter concatenated with "Hello " as I desire, but I only get "Hello " returned.
Please help !

Comment: What's the import for `@PathParam`? It should be `import javax.ws.rs.PathParam`.

Comment: It was "import javax.websocket.server.PathParam" earlier. But after changing it to "import javax.ws.rs.PathParam", it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score -1):

```
@Get
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Path("/simple/{tem}")
public String test(@PathVariable("tem") String tem) {
    String t = "Hello " + tem;
    return t;
}
```

Comment: Have you at least [read the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50864262/not-able-to-access-parameter-passed-in-restful-web-service#comment88736046_50864262)?